# Select the first row of the last group

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I am trying to query a 2012 SQL-Server about some data.

Data is in the following table

| From_Date | To_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-11-29 | 2022-02-23 |
| 2022-02-23 | 2022-02-26 |
| 2022-02-27 | 2022-03-01 |
| 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-04 |
| 2022-03-07 | 2022-03-10 |
| 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-15 |

What I want to get is the first date in sequential block of dates. These blocks in the example provided would be row 1->2, row 3->4, and row 5->6. Where I would want to return the from_date column in row 5 as it is the first date in the last block of sequential dates.

I have tried various approaches but I am not that familiar with SQL so I was hoping anyone here could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the output that you want in form of a table?

Comment: In this case, I would want to return the from_date column in row 5. So 2022-03-07. As it is the first value in the latest consecutive date block.

Comment: What's the `active` column?  Can it be used to find the last group?  Does it need to be derived from the data?  It is just a red herring?  *(If it's not relevant, please remove it, it's a distraction.)*  Also, your question says you want to return a row, and your comment says you just want a single date; please edit your question to clarify precisely what you want.

Comment: Removed, it is a requirement that it has to be active, but it does not really aid in finding the correct date. So removed it from this example as all that would have to be added would be a equality check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH
  gaps AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN from_date = LEAD(to_date) OVER (ORDER BY from_date DESC) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  AS is_first_row_of_group
  FROM
    your_table
)
SELECT TOP (1)
  from_date
FROM
  gaps
WHERE
  is_first_row_of_group = 1
ORDER BY
  from_date DESC
```